# AVD creation failed

Tags: android, eclipse

I have found a lot of questions nearly similar to mine on stackoverflow. Unfortunately, I did not find a good answer to my Q. So, the question is :

I wrote  a small "helloworld" app, in Eclipse Juno, for Android. I try to create an AVD. I filled all the boxes with appropriate settings:

```
     - Device : 3.3" WQVGA
     - Target: Android 1.5 - API Level 3 (this is chosen automatically)
     - CPU / ABI - ARM (armeabil) (btw - what are ABI and armeabi ?)
     - Keyboard: HW key present (checked)
     - Skin: QVGA-L
     - Memory option:  RAM: 512     VM Heap: 16
     - Internal storage: 200 MiB
     - SD Card: Size 512MiB
     - Emulation option: Use Host GPU (checked)
```

These are the setings. No matter how I wait, the OK button remains grayed and can not be triggered, so I am not able to create an AVD. What is wrong ? What must I do ?
(Android SQK has been installed using *installer_r20.0.3-windows*)

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Did you enter the name?

Comment: Android 1.5?! can you at least try it with a more recent version of Android like 4.0 and up?

Comment: i remember there was a bug in the eclipse tools - maybe this one helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6

Comment: @user3249477 - I entered the name : without imagination I called it "myAVD"

Comment: Now use a higher API and give it a shot.

Comment: @Morrison Chang - I tried the version you mentioned (and not only). Same thing.